# Ideals in $C[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $C[0,1]$ be the ring of continuous real-valued functions on $[0,1]$, with addition and multiplication defined pointwise. 
>   For any subset $S$ of $C[0,1]$ let $Z(S)=\{f\in C[0,1]: f(x)=0 \text{ for all }x\in S\}$. Then which of the following statements are true?
>   (a) If $Z(S)$ is an ideal in $C[0,1]$ then $S$ is closed in $[0,1]$.
>   (b) If $Z(S)$ is a maximal ideal then $S$ has only one point.
>   (c) If $S$ has only one point then $Z(S)$ is a maximal ideal.

(a) Not necessary: if I take $S=(1/2,1/3)$ still $Z(S)$ is an ideal.

(b) I know that maximal ideals in $C[0,1]$ come in this way (I don't know the proof rigorously), i.e. $C_a=\{f\in C[0,1]:f(a)=0\}$ so $S$ may be finite or countable set? So I guess $(b)$ is a true statement and for the same reason $(c)$ is also true. But I will be happy if someone can explain me a bit about (b) and (c). Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide us with a reference?

Comment: it is not from a book just a question paper of past year exam paper

Answer (score 5):

To show that $C_a$ is maximal define $\phi:C[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ with $\phi(f)=f(a)$ and then use the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem_2).
 For the converse define $\phi:C[0,1]\longrightarrow C(S), \ f \mapsto f|_S$ to show that $C[0,1]\
/Z(S)$ is isomorphic to $C(S)$.

Then use that $m \leq R$ is maximal $\iff R/m$ is a field.

Comment: $S$ can be uncountable or countably infinite to be  a maximal ideal?

Comment: @Kuttus: $Z(S)$ is maximal iff $S$ is an one point set.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to proving maximality:  If $S, T$ are two nonempty subsets of $[0,1]$ with $T \subset S$, then $Z(S) \subset Z(T)$.   So $Z(S)$ is maximal if and only if it does not contain any proper subsets -- i.e., it must be a one-point set.

Comment: I suppose you want to say $T\subsetneq S\implies Z(S)\subsetneq Z(T)$. Well, this deserves a proof, don't you think?